# How To Wire Humidistat and Humidifier - Honeywell

Tags: hvac, humidifier

I am looking for advice on how to wire my new humidistat with my furance and humidifier. First, here are the components I'm working with:

- Furnace: Carrier WeatherMaker Infinity (Model 58MVP100 14120)
- Humidifier: Honeywell HE265B1005
- Humidistat: HoneywellH6062

Background: Old humidistat (Honeywell H1008A) quit working so ordered this new one. The humidifier is a Bypass, with both humidistat and humidifier mounted on the Return side. Humidifier is hooked into COLD water line.

What I'd Like: Since humidifier is on Return side and hooked into cold, I'd want the humidifier to kick on when humidity reads low and there is a call for heat. (Feel free to let me know if you feel differently).

Where I am at in the setup: I do have the humidistat hooked up to constant 24V and the Outdoor Sensor hooked up and tested.

What I need help with:
My furnace does have a 24V HUM terminal which kicks on during call for heat, so I know I can use that, I just need to know how to hook it in. On my humidistat I have two U terminals for the humidifier, and I need to know how to hook those up to the furnace and humidifier solenoid. I will post some pictures. I know the bottom U humidistat terminal gets wired to one of the humidifier solenoid wires. The top U terminal is what I need help with....and then I need help with what wire to hook into the second humidifier solenoid wire. One note, my furnace does have the HUM 24V terminal, as well as a HUMR (HUM relay) terminal. [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Seriously nice job for your first post! I removed  "first post" because we can tell, but nobody much cares :), and I tweaked the formatting a bit for readability (click the link above my name and you can see the changes I made so you know for the future). While you're waiting for an answer (I don't have one for you), you can take the [tour] and browse the [help] so you can learn how this Q&A forum differs from most general discussion boards so you can make the most of it. Welcome!

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the formatting assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It goes "HUM -> U, other U->solenoid terminal, other solenoid terminal->C"

In order to get your humidifier to work, you need to create a closed circuit through the humidifier solenoid to bring 24VAC to it.  Since we know the HUM 24V terminal is a 24VAC source from the wiring diagram you posted with the C terminal as its corresponding return, we can pull 24VAC from that and feed it to one U terminal on the humidistat.  The other U terminal, then, connects down to one of the humidifier's solenoid connections; finally, the remaining terminal on the humidifier solenoid gets connected to the C wire on your furnace.  The result is a closed circuit that only is energized when your furnace permits humidification *and* the humidistat calls for water, just as you wish it to work.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try today. Out of curiosity, do you happen to know what the HUMR (relay) terminal is meant for?

Comment: @Nick if it's a single terminal, then it's for a 120V humidifier connection

Comment: I was able to wire today (finally), using your recommendation, ThreePhaseEel...and I can confirm success! Thank you very much! 

Humidity level was low and a call for heat came through, and sure enough the humidifier solenoid opened up to let water soak the pad. Water shutoff once the call for heat ended. :)

Comment: @Nick -- we thank folks around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)

Comment: Upvoted and accepted :)